# Exit Aframe full screen

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I have an embedded a-scene element, where users can click to enter the Aframe full screen mode. On a specific event (user navigated to specific position in a-scene), I want to trigger an automatic exit of the full screen mode. This would be the equivalent of user pressing the ESC key, but programmatically. How can I do this?

Here is my a-scene code:

```
...
<a-scene id="3d-view" embedded style="z-index: 9999;">
<a-entity position="33 0 -33" rotation="0 180 0" id="camera" camera="userHeight: 1.6" listener>
</a-entity>
...
<!-- Lighting -->
<a-light type="ambient" color="#bbb"></a-light>
<a-light color="#ccc" position="0 30 0" distance="100" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light>
<a-light color="#ccc" position="3 10 -10" distance="50" intensity="0.4" type="point"></a-light>
<a-entity id="a"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
...
```

Here is the method for exiting full screen:

```
var obj3d = document.querySelector("#camera").object3D;
AFRAME.registerComponent('listener', {
    tick: function () {
        if(Math.abs(obj3d.position.x) < 35) {
            //HERE IT SHOULD EXIT FULL SCREEN IF WE ARE IN FULL SCREEN
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.el.sceneEl.exitVR()`

or

```
exitFullscreen();

   function exitFullscreen () {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't exit the focus of the cursor though. so when the user clicks on the embedded scene, she still has to press escape to get back the cursor. any ideas how to fully get out of the embedded scene with the UI controls?

Comment: Are you using pointer lock? You can do `document.exitPointerLock();`

Comment: document.exitPointerLock(); and exitVR() together solved it